# How can i set the json response string to the button text in android

Tags: android, json, web-services

Hi i am new to android i try to set the response string of a web service to the text of a button, the button is inside a listview..i have tried the below code but it will not work..how can i change the text of the button.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements RegisterContactToServer.AsyncResponseListener {
    ListView lv;
    Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_contact);

        cursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] from={ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
        int[] to={R.id.name_entry,R.id.number_entry};

        ContactList listadapter=new ContactList(this,R.layout.single_row1,cursor,from,to);

        setListAdapter(listadapter);
        lv=getListView();
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    }

    class ContactList extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements Filterable {
        private Context context;
        String strfromMobileno="";
        private int layout;
        public ContactList(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            this.context=context;
            this.layout=layout;

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        }

          @Override
        public void bindView(View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {

            int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String name = c.getString(nameCol);

            int noCol = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String no = c.getString(noCol);
         final CheckBox p1 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            final CheckBox p2 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
            final CheckBox p3 = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);



            final TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
            if (name_text != null) {
                name_text.setText(name);
            }

            final TextView no_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.number_entry);
            if (no_text != null) {
                no_text.setText(no);
            }
            final Button btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                    String contactName = name_text.getText().toString();
                    String contactNo  =no_text.getText().toString();

                    /*Intent intent = getIntent();
                    String fromMobileno = intent.getExtras().getString("MN");*/



                    Contact contact=new Contact();
                    contact.setFromMobileno(contactName);
                    contact.setToMobileno(contactNo);


                    if(p1.isChecked()){
                        int priority1=Integer.parseInt(p1.getText().toString());
                        contact.setPriority1(1);
                        }else{contact.setPriority1(0);}

                        if(p2.isChecked())
                        {
                        int priority2=Integer.parseInt(p2.getText().toString());
                        contact.setPriority2(1);
                        }else{contact.setPriority2(0);}

                        if(p3.isChecked()){
                        int priority3=Integer.parseInt(p3.getText().toString());
                        contact.setPriority3(1);
                        }else{contact.setPriority3(0);}
                        contact.setStatus(statusR);

                   if (!contactName.equals("") ){

                     RegisterContactToServer reg=new RegisterContactToServer(context);
                        reg.execute(contact);

                      }




                }
            });
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onresponse(String status, String jsonData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_row1, null, false);

        final Button btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setText(jsonData);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }}
```

Comment: TL;DR, you should try stating your question as clear and as short as possible. Try avoiding long "copy-paste" of code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the content of the Adapter you are using to populate your ListView, with the data you would like in the list element.  Then you would instruct the system to refresh the ListView (notifyDataSetChanged()) and redraw the ListView with the newly refreshed data.